# When is `stage is None` in pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Some official pytorch lightning [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/datamodules.html) have code that refer to `stage` as `Optional[str]` with for example the following code

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import random_split, DataLoader

# Note - you must have torchvision installed for this example
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision import transforms


class MNISTDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, data_dir: str = "./"):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

    def prepare_data(self):
        # download
        MNIST(self.data_dir, train=True, download=True)
        MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False, download=True)

    def setup(self, stage: Optional[str] = None):

        # Assign train/val datasets for use in dataloaders
        if stage == "fit" or stage is None:
            mnist_full = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=True, transform=self.transform)
            self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [55000, 5000])

        # Assign test dataset for use in dataloader(s)
        if stage == "test" or stage is None:
            self.mnist_test = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False, transform=self.transform)

        if stage == "predict" or stage is None:
            self.mnist_predict = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False, transform=self.transform)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_train, batch_size=32)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_val, batch_size=32)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=32)

    def predict_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_predict, batch_size=32)
```

When does stage take the value of None? I could find no docs describing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trainer will never send `stage=None` to the setup hook, or any of the other hooks that take this argument. The type is annotated optional and the default value is None for historical reasons. The values will always be one of "fit", "validate", "test", "predict".

There is an [RFC to change this](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/14062) to a required argument to avoid confusion. The link provides some more context why it has been like this for the past.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [from](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/datamodules.html#setup):

> This method expects a `stage` argument. It is used to separate setup
> logic for `trainer.{fit,validate,test,predict}`. If `setup` is called with
> `stage=None`, we assume all stages have been set-up.

Here is a simple code example; if you use this `LightningDataModule` snippet:

```py
class MNISTDataModule(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, data_dir: str = "path/to/dir", batch_size: int = 256 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 64):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def setup(self, stage):
        print(stage)
```

when running:

```py
MNIST_dm = MNISTDataModule(PATH_DATASETS)

trainer.fit(mnist_model, MNIST_dm)
trainer.validate(mnist_model, MNIST_dm)
trainer.test(mnist_model, MNIST_dm)
MNIST_dm.setup(stage="None")
```

you will see this printed:

```bash
TrainerFn.FITTING
TrainerFn.VALIDATING
TrainerFn.TESTING
None
```

It is `None` when you set it explicitly to `None`, otherwise it takes the stage name that it is being called

Comment: Thanks, but still I am lacking a real life use case which required to explicitly call `setup` with `None`

Comment: @Gulzar The Trainer will never send in stage=None. This is just a default value that we set for backward-compatibility. It will always be one of the stage values when the hook gets called.

Comment: @awaelchli I think this should be the answer (which I will accept) in this case. Please also provide a reference for that.